# How do I pass a google authentication token (obtained in iOS) to a google-app-engine web servlet?

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I'm new to web server programming so maybe I'm doing this the wrong way, but here's what I'm trying to do:

1. The user authenticates using a native iOS app against the server "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me".  I'm using the , 
   [GTMOAuth2 classes](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/) to handle the authorization.  I've successfully retrieved a valid token, so this part works.
2. I'm now trying to POST JSON data to a google-app-engine web servlet as an authenticated user by using the authentication token I obtained in step 1.  Here's the code I'm using:

   ```
   - (void)postDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict toURL:(NSMutableString *)urlString     withAuthToken:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authToken delegate:(id)connectDelegate
   {

   if( ![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict] )
   {
       NSLog(@"JSON Data is Invalid!");
       return;
   }
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                  options:0 error:nil];
   NSMutableString *serverURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:urlString];
   //DEBUG
   NSLog(@"sent URL: %@", serverURL);

   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:serverURL];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

   // Execute URL Asynchronously
   // Make sure we "Post" the data to the server
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
   [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                  [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

   // We need to send the authentication information to the server.
   [request setValue:CLIENT_ID forHTTPHeaderField:@"client_id"];
   [request setValue:CLIENT_SECRET forHTTPHeaderField:@"client_secret"];
   [request setValue:authToken.accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization: GoogleLogin auth"];
   // Make sure we can authenticate on HTTP instead of just HTTPS
   authToken.shouldAuthorizeAllRequests=YES;   // USED FOR TESTING ON LOCALHOST ONLY!!!


   // Let's Try the Fetcher method...
   GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
   [myFetcher setAuthorizer:authToken];
   [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
               didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
    return;
   }
   ```

Currently the server I'm trying to post to is is running on "http://localhost:8888/mywebapp".

1. On the web server, I'm trying to authenticate the user using the following java code:

   ```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
               throws IOException {
   // Perform Authentication...
   UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
   User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

   if( user != null ) {
       System.out.println("User: "+user.getNickname());
   } else {
       sendError( "You must login first!",  resp );
       return;
   }
   ...
   ```

The UserService never indicates a user is logged in.  I've tried several different things, but haven't had any success.  My app just gets the "You must login first!" error message.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

1. I had to switch to the OAuth 1 protocol instead of the OAuth 2 protocol.  According to the documentation I read, the OAuth 2 isn't supported for Google App Engine yet (Does anyone know differently?).  So I used the library [GTM-OAUTH](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/) instead of the GTM-OAUTH2 library in my iOS app.  I used the "OAuthSampleTouch" example as a basis for using the library.
2. I needed to register my google-app-engine URL with Google, using https://accounts.google.com/managedomains.
   That gave me a ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret I could use in my iPhone app when calling the GTM-OAUTH Library.
3. I modified my GAE server code to use the OAUTH token:

   ```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
       throws IOException {
   // Perform Authentication...
     User user = null;
     try {
     OAuthService oathService = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
     user = oathService.getCurrentUser();
     System.out.println("Logged in! YAY!!!");
     } catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
        System.out.println("Authentication Failed! "+e);
     }
     ...
   ```

I also appended the Token into the URL, I'm not sure if this is required or not...

Example:
        URL="https://my-app.appspot.com/myservlet?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: Oh yeah, I also couldn't get the google-app-engine to work properly using the eclipse plugin.  Once I deployed it to the actual server it worked perfectly.

Comment: GTM Oauth requires a scope string. What did you set for this?

Comment: I believe I use: @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email".  Sorry for the late reply...